# Prestashop: save images with relative path?

Tags: file, prestashop-1.6

When I upload an image to a CMS page (Prestshop) it is saved using absolute path. This is very bad if you work in your localhost and then after you move the site to a remote server.

How can I change this? so that the image gets saved with a relative path:

The images are saved like this `http://www.example.com/img/cms/my-image.jpg`

I need it to be like this `img/cms/my-image.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at tinymce config file `/js/admin/tinymce.inc.js`:

```js
function tinySetup(config)
{
    if(!config)
        config = {};

    //var editor_selector = 'rte';

    if (typeof config.editor_selector != 'undefined')
        config.selector = '.'+config.editor_selector;

    default_config = {
        selector: ".rte" ,
        plugins : "colorpicker link image paste pagebreak table contextmenu filemanager table code media autoresize textcolor anchor",
        browser_spellcheck : true,
        toolbar1 : "code,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,alignleft,aligncenter,alignright,alignfull,formatselect,|,blockquote,colorpicker,pasteword,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,|,link,unlink,|,anchor,|,media,image",
        toolbar2: "",
        external_filemanager_path: ad+"/filemanager/",
        filemanager_title: "File manager" ,
        external_plugins: { "filemanager" : ad+"/filemanager/plugin.min.js"},
        language: iso,
        skin: "prestashop",
        statusbar: false,
        relative_urls : false,
        convert_urls: false,
        entity_encoding: "raw",
        extended_valid_elements : "em[class|name|id]",
        valid_children : "+*[*]",
        valid_elements:"*[*]",
        menu: {
            edit: {title: 'Edit', items: 'undo redo | cut copy paste | selectall'},
            insert: {title: 'Insert', items: 'media image link | pagebreak'},
            view: {title: 'View', items: 'visualaid'},
            format: {title: 'Format', items: 'bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | formats | removeformat'},
            table: {title: 'Table', items: 'inserttable tableprops deletetable | cell row column'},
            tools: {title: 'Tools', items: 'code'}
        }
    };

    $.each(default_config, function(index, el)
    {
        if (config[index] === undefined )
            config[index] = el;
    });

    tinyMCE.init(config);
}
```

There's a value called `relative_urls` set to `false` by default.